# Its not printing everything I want it to print

Tags: python

This code needs to accept two points on a line and returns the values for `m`and `b` in the equation `y = m*x + b. (m = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)` and `b = y1 - (m*x1)`. I coded it to do that but I'm at the part where I'm listing all the information found: ("the first point is:", "and:", "the second point is:", "m =", "B =" and etc). I noticed that from the return print list its only running the first print and isn't running all 5 prints. I tried adding \n for it to write it in a new line but it didn't work. How can I make it that it lists every single return print I coded and say the 2 points that it randomly has chosen.

```
import sys
import sys
import math
import random

number = random.randint(1,100)
number2 = random.randint(1,100)
number3 = random.randint(1,100)
number4 = random.randint(1,100)



def line_equation(x2,y2,x1,y1):
    rise = y2-y1
    run = x2-x1
    m = rise/run
    b = y2/(m*x2)
    return print("m = " + str(m) + " and b = " + str(b))
    return print("the first point is: ",number)
    return print("and: ",number2)
    return print("the second point is: ",number3)
    return print("and: ",number4)

line_equation(number, number2, number3, number4)
```

Comment: A Python function can only return once. Just leave out all the return statements. Write `print("m = " + str(m) + " and b = " + str(b))` without the return in front of it.

Comment: In addition to the observation that `return` returns control to the calling function, which is correct and is immediate solution to your problem, it is also worth pointing out that the `print` function is executed for its side-effect (causing some text to appear on the screen) and does not return any value. Therefore `return print(...)` will always be a pointless instruction.

Answer (score 3):

"return" will literally return to the caller (therefore leaving the function). That is why the remaining lines are not printed.

This should do what you want.

```
def line_equation(x2,y2,x1,y1):
    rise = y2-y1
    run = x2-x1
    m = rise/run
    b = y2/(m*x2)
    print("m = " + str(m) + " and b = " + str(b))
    print("the first point is: ",number)
    print("and: ",number2)
    print("the second point is: ",number3)
    print("and: ",number4)
    return # This is optional
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning from the function at the first print, remove all the `return` keywords.

Answer (score 2):

You specify `return` when you want the function/code flow to end. `return` generally is the last thing that will be executed inside a function (not 100% truth, but *generally*).

Also, one uses `return` when they actually need to return a value, if not, you can just end the function. So your code probably should be:

```
import sys
import sys
import math
import random

number = random.randint(1,100)
number2 = random.randint(1,100)
number3 = random.randint(1,100)
number4 = random.randint(1,100)



def line_equation(x2,y2,x1,y1):
    rise = y2-y1
    run = x2-x1
    m = rise/run
    b = y2/(m*x2)
    print("m = " + str(m) + " and b = " + str(b))
    print("the first point is: ",number)
    print("and: ",number2)
    print("the second point is: ",number3)
    print("and: ",number4)

line_equation(number, number2, number3, number4)
```